# Is transit gateway available under the co-existence of Express Route Gateway and VPN Gateway in Azure?

Tags: azure

I am planning to use hub and spoke network topology in my Azure environment. At the same time, it is required to establish a connection between my on-premise network and Azure environment using Express Route with S2S VPN as the backup.

I wonder if I still can use my S2S VPN/Express Route as the transit gateway in this scenario? If it is okay, can I choose S2S VPN gateway as my transit gateway? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "as the backup"?

Comment: My plan is it acts like disaster recovery passive backup solution to the ExpressRoute connection

Comment: You might need to use Azure Event Hubs for a first-party solution. Upvoting for visibility.